# How do you unit test JOIN queries in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, testing, join, mocking, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize to access a database from NodeJS. The database has a few tables with relationships, and I have a query that joins tables i.e. something like this

```
const result = await modelA.findAll({
    ...
    include: [
      {
        model: modelB,
        ...
      }
    ]
})
```

I have been struggling to find a good way to test this.

I have looked at

- `sequelize-mock`
- `sequelize-test-helpers`

None of which mention anything about testing **associated** Sequelize models.

I have tried to create mock models with `sequelize-mock`, and re-define the relationships between the models, but that also did not work so I am not sure if it is supported (*by did not work I mean the above query I made did not actually do a join with the two provided mock models, despite the attempted association definition between them*).

Alternatively, I could just mock the return value of `findAll(`, but I am aware that that return object is Sequelize implementation specific so it would be ideal if I could avoid constructing that object myself. Also I feel like that defeats the purpose of having the above mocking libraries as well.

Any one know a good way to approach this?